# Xcode Device Simulator Files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I have been clearing some space from my drive and noticed that there are 183 folders inside my Developer>CoreSimulator>Devices folder. Are all of these required or are some of these simulators for older versions of iOS. When I look inside some of the folders they contain a file called device.plist that says the Sim Runtime is iOS-8-4. Is there any way to remove these old files?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```

Core Simulator folder is familiar for many `Xcode` users. It’s simulator’s territory; thats where it stores app data. It’s obvious that you can toss the older version simulator folder/folders if you no longer support your apps for those versions. And, it’s safer to use ‘Reset content and Settings’ option from menu to delete all of your app data in a Simulator.

Tip:

```
Objective-C
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]; 

Swift
NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSDocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSUserDomainMask).lastObject()
```

Will print the full path to the document directory folder.